# Laravel Route apiResource (difference between apiResource and resource in route)

Tags: laravel-5, model-view-controller, routes, resources

I'm using `apiResource` in Route which is using `(index, create, show, update, destroy)` methods in `exampleController`. When I would like to use show method the route wont work. what shall I do? I think it is because of `{fruits}` but I do not how solve it?

```
Route::apiResource('/fruit/{fruits}/apples', 'exampleController');
```

My route in browser is:

```
localhost:8000/api/fruits/testFruitSlug/apples/testAppleSlug
```

***difference between apiResource and resource in route:*** `Route::apiResource()` only creates routes for index, store, show, update and destroy while `Route::resource()` also adds a create and edit route which don't make sense in an API context.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To quickly generate an API resource controller that does not include the create or edit methods, use the --api switch when executing the make:controller command:

```
php artisan make:controller API/PhotoController --api
```

Try using the command line to generate your controller. It will save you stress. You can then do this in your route

```
Route::apiResource('photos', 'PhotoController');
```

Comment: Even Route::apiResources(['photos' => 'PhotoController', pages'' => 'PageController']);

Answer (score 50):

Already peoples added answers, I am just adding the route differences as visually :

## Normal Resource controller

```
Route::resource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Gives you these named routes:

```
Verb          Path                        Action  Route Name
GET           /users                      index   users.index
GET           /users/create               create  users.create
POST          /users                      store   users.store
GET           /users/{user}               show    users.show
GET           /users/{user}/edit          edit    users.edit
PUT|PATCH     /users/{user}               update  users.update
DELETE        /users/{user}               destroy users.destroy
```

## Api Resource controller

```
Route::apiResource('users', 'UsersController');
```

Gives you these named routes:

```
Verb          Path                        Action  Route Name
GET           /users                      index   users.index
POST          /users                      store   users.store
GET           /users/{user}               show    users.show
PUT|PATCH     /users/{user}               update  users.update
DELETE        /users/{user}               destroy users.destroy
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my question in below way:

```
public function show(Fruits $fruits, Apples $apples){

}
```

I found that I should give all variables in my function however I did not use all of them.