# When you give a 404 NOT FOUND , even though I am using it route resource . I don't go to any page

Tags: laravel, eloquent

When you give a `404 NOT FOUND`, even though I am using it route resource. I don't go to any page

```php
Route::resource('/' , ClientController::class)
```

```html
<tbody>
    @forelse($clients as $client)
        <tr>
            <th scope="row">{{$client->id}}</th>
            <td>{{$client->email}}</td>
            <td>{{$client->password}}</td>
            <td>{{$client->city}}</td>
            <td><a href="{{route('edit',$client->id)}}"  >Update</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
    @empty
        <h1>pas de client</h1>
    @endforelse
</tbody>
```

```php
public function edit($id)
{
    return $id;
}
```

Comment: What does `php artisan route:list` return?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54721576/laravel-route-apiresource-difference-between-apiresource-and-resource-in-route#:~:text=difference%20between%20apiResource%20and%20resource%20in%20route%3A%20Route%3A%3AapiResource,sense%20in%20an%20API%20context.

Comment: in console **run php artisan optimize:clear **

Answer (score 1):

Your return needs to go somewhere, try:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

or:

```
public function edit($id)
{
    return redirect()->route('route.name');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::resource('/' , ClientController::class);
```

Change the above to:

```
Route::resource('/client' , ClientController::class);
```

Then, in the blade for edit:

```html
<td><a href="{{route('client.edit',$client->id)}}" >Update</a></td>
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?